# Is it possible to add a timer to the actionbar on android?

Tags: android, android-actionbar, countdowntimer

I'd like a simple `mm:ss` timer to be displayed on my actionbar, be able to pick the number of minutes to start counting down from and then call a method once it's at 0. Is this possible and how?

Comment: have you tried so far?

Comment: Here is an example http://thegeekyland.blogspot.com/2014/07/android-count-down-timer-in-actionbar.html

Answer (score 16):

I've managed to do that by adding a `TextView` to the Action Bar as an [Action View](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html#ActionView) in the menu, then updating it at regular intervals using a `CountDownTimer`.
(Tested on an Android 3.0 emulator, an Android 4.3 emulator and a real device running Android 4.3).

Here's the XML for the menu item. Note that `actionViewClass="android.widget.TextVew"`
 (showAsAction and actionViewClass don't have the android namespace because I'm using the support action bar).

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:compatibility="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" >

    <item android:id="@+id/break_timer"
          android:title="@string/break_timer_title"
          compatibility:showAsAction="always"
          compatibility:actionViewClass="android.widget.TextView" />

</menu>
```

In `onCreateOptionsMenu`, I find the `MenuItem` and call `getActionView` to assign it to private `TextView`, `timerText`. I also apply some padding here, so that it's not right at the edge of the screen.

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.break_timer, menu);

    MenuItem timerItem = menu.findItem(R.id.break_timer);
    timerText = (TextView) MenuItemCompat.getActionView(timerItem);

    timerText.setPadding(10, 0, 10, 0); //Or something like that...

    startTimer(30000, 1000); //One tick every second for 30 seconds
    return true;
}
```

I have a method called `startTimer` to start a `CountDownTimer` and update `timerText` in its `onTick`. I call `startTimer` from `onCreateOptionsMenu` to ensure that `timerText` is not accessed before it has been initialised. (Previously, I called `startTimer` from `onCreate`, but got a `NullPointerException`).

```
private void startTimer(long duration, long interval) {

    CountDownTimer timer = new CountDownTimer(duration, interval) {

        @Override
        public void onFinish() {
            //TODO Whatever's meant to happen when it finishes
        }

        @Override
        public void onTick(long millisecondsLeft) {
            int secondsLeft = (int) Math.round((millisecondsLeft / (double) 1000));
            timerText.setText(secondsToString(secondsLeft));
        }
    };

    timer.start();
}
```

I'm sure that anyone reading this will know a better way to convert an integer number of seconds to a timecode such as "00:00:00", but just in case I'll share the `secondsToString` method I used in `onTick`, above.

```
private String secondsToString(int improperSeconds) {

    //Seconds must be fewer than are in a day

    Time secConverter = new Time();

    secConverter.hour = 0;
    secConverter.minute = 0;
    secConverter.second = 0;

    secConverter.second = improperSeconds;
    secConverter.normalize(true);

    String hours = String.valueOf(secConverter.hour);
    String minutes = String.valueOf(secConverter.minute);
    String seconds = String.valueOf(secConverter.second);

    if (seconds.length() < 2) {
        seconds = "0" + seconds;
    }
    if (minutes.length() < 2) {
        minutes = "0" + minutes;
    }
    if (hours.length() < 2) {
        hours = "0" + hours;
    }

    String timeString = hours + ":" + minutes + ":" + seconds;
    return timeString;
}
```

Comment: NullPointerException at timerText.setText();

Answer (score 3):

**Menu xml**

```
<item
                android:id="@+id/counter"
                android:title=""
                android:showAsAction="always">
</item>
```

**public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu)"

```
long timer = 10000;
public Boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) 
{
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);

       final MenuItem  counter = menu.findItem(R.id.counter);
        new CountDownTimer(timer, 1000) {

          public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
             long millis = millisUntilFinished; 
             String  hms = (TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toHours(millis))+":"+(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(millis) -TimeUnit.HOURS.toMinutes(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toHours(millis)))+":"+ (TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(millis) - TimeUnit.MINUTES.toSeconds(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(millis))); 

             counter.setTitle(hms);
             timer = millis;

            }

        public void onFinish() {
             counter.setTitle("done!");
            }
         }.start();

         return  true;

 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes it's possible to add timer in toolbar action
use this code in Java:

```
private void startTimer(long duration, long interval) {

CountDownTimer timer = new CountDownTimer(duration, interval) {

    @Override
    public void onFinish() {
        //TODO Whatever's meant to happen when it finishes
    }

    @Override
    public void onTick(long millisecondsLeft) {
        int secondsLeft = (int) Math.round((millisecondsLeft / (double) 1000));
        timerText.setText(secondsToString(secondsLeft));
    }
};

timer.start();
}
```

and also use 
menu file defined timer id just like this

if learn more the visit youtube :)