# Is it possible to use android.widget.chronometer inside the actionbar?

Tags: android, timer, android-appcompat

I wanted to add a timer inside the actionbar. I already found this solution here: [Is it possible to add a timer to the actionbar on android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17430477/is-it-possible-to-add-a-timer-to-the-actionbar-on-android) which uses `compatibility:actionViewClass="android.widget.TextView"` 
and then using a timer wich updates on each tick the string value.

I wandered if anyone already tried using `app:actionViewClass="android.widget.chronometer"`

It would be something like that for the menu:

```
<menu 
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
     <item android:id="@+id/action_live_clock"
       android:title=""
       app:showAsAction="always"
       app:actionViewClass="android.widget.chronometer"/>
</menu>
```

And then in the corresponding activity:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu)
{
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.test_chrono, menu);
        MenuItem timerItem = menu.findItem(R.id.action_live_clock);
        Chronometer timer = (Chronometer) timerItem.getActionView();
        timer.setBase(SystemClock.elapsedRealtime());
        timer.start();
        return true;
}
```

But when I check after getActionView the timer value is Null. Did I miss something or is this just not possible?

(as ActionBar I am using the appcompat from the latest support library)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can allways add a custom view to the actionbar/toolbar. Just google for that.

Comment: I added a custom layout inside my menu item (action_live_clock above). Like this : app:actionLayout="@layout/menu_item_clock" and the layout contained a chronometer element. And it worked! Thanks!